# Edit a STL file using python Blender library

Tags: python, linux, blender

I am using python's library from Blender v.2.69, and I was wondering if I can modify an STL file via command line, I'm thinking to add simple solid like a cube or something.

http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_69_1/info_quickstart.html

And if not, what library can I use to do so?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You won't find a way to edit an STL file directly in blender. With blender you could import the STL file, alter the content and then export to an STL file.

Blender's python API allows you to perform tasks within blender so you could use it to automate part of the process - maybe all. For python scripts that run within blender you will find more help at [blender.stackexchange.com](https://blender.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Thanks @sambler :) do you know where can I get an example of the process of import the STL file, alter the content and then export to an STL file? thanks!

Comment: The stl import/export is enabled by default, File->Import->STL - Shift-A->Mesh->Cube will add a plain cube. Any introduction to blender tutorial will help get you started. [BlenderCookie has intro videos](http://cgcookie.com/blender/cgc-courses/blender-basics-introduction-for-beginners/) The blender wiki has links to a lot of [beginner tutorials](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Tutorials/Resources/External_links) and [blender.stackexchange](http://blender.stackexchange.com/) for any questions when you get stuck.